# Data sheet to a single SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, access

Is there a way to import two (2) separate access data sheet to a single SharePoint list? To make it clear, there is an Employee access database and Equipment (Labtop, Blackberries, and etc) access database. The client want to manage these data from a single SP list.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two Sharepoint lists, one for **Employees** and one for Equipment.  In order to 'link' them in to one list, you would then make 'lookup' fields.

For example - go in **Employees** List Settings>Create Column>MyLookUpField.

`Get information from:` **Equipment** list (Sharepoint will allow you to pick from all lists that are on the same site collection).

`In this column`: choose the Equipment field from your **Equipment List**.

***Notes***

For MyLookUpField, use your own field name of course - perhaps call it 'Equipment' if that would make sense.

You will need to make one line per Employee, use the Lookup field to indicate the Equipment for that Employee.